# LTspice op-amp simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I'm using LTspice to try to better my understanding of op-amps. In the following simulation of a simple follower (using LTspice's op-amp2), why do the transient and the AC analysis seem to give such different results?

In the AC analysis it actually shows a gain of +3 dB at a frequency around 7 MHz. In my understanding the gain should be unity until it hits the falling open loop gain curve at the unity gain bandwidth fT. The phase shift at 7 MHz from the graph is ~ -70°.

When running a transient simulation at 7 MHz I get seemingly inconsistent results, with the gain being much less than one and the phase shift looking closer to 180°.

Am I doing something wrong in LTspice, or misunderstanding something?

LTspice simulations:

[image: AC analysis]

[image: Transient analysis]

Comment: It totally depends on the op-amp type. Some op-amps will produce a small peak close to where you see it.

Comment: @Andy aka. Thanks, this was just with the LT spice general purpose opamp2. Even so why then does the transient analysis show a markedly different result at 7 MHz, have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Opamp2 is meaningless as a model because it doesn't have a data sheet. Why not use a proper op-amp model and see what happens and compare it with the data sheet and see if the data sheet does indicate a rise in the AC response (hint: a lot of real op-amps will have a peak in the AC response in this area).

Comment: opamp2 uses a subcircuit file that may be specified by the user, so it's impossible to know what you have.  Maybe try one of the universal op amps so we can have a common ground to discuss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the **Universal**Opamp2, or Opamp2 model? The Opamp2 model needs a subcircuit file which you don't mention.

Using the UniversalOpamp2 model with a Transient analysis, using a 1 Vp input amplitude, the output will be slew rate limited with no modifications to the model. In AC analysis, there is no peaking. The slew rate specified in the UniversalOpamp2 model is 10Meg which is equivalent to 10 V/µs. The maximum output voltage of a sine wave with minimal distortion due to slew rate limitation is given by

$$ V_p = {SlewRate \over {2 \pi f}} = {10e6 \over {2 \pi \; 7e6}} \approx {0.23}$$

If slew rate limited, you would expect to see the output waveform approach a triangle wave as shown in the example below. For your case with the unknown model, try lowering the input voltage to 0.1 Vp and see if things jibe.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helpful. I was in fact using the "UniversalOpAmp2" (sorry for the confusion on that, I hadn't event spotted the other one). Comparing the parameters to your screenshot I saw mine was set to "level3a" whereas yours was "level2". Setting to level2 I get the exact same result as you. If I then reduce amplitudes to 100mV so it is within slew rate I also see the reduction of the signal @7MHz seen in the transient analysis matches up with that predicted in the ac analysis. Perfect :-). I do wonder then what the level3a setting is doing.

Comment: The differences in the levels are explained in the reply in this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590607/is-the-universalopamp2-in-ltspice-useful-for-stability-in-capacitive-drive-app). Level2 is a single pole model, level3a is a two-pole model.